# C# OLEDB connection, is it possible to get windows username on data source directory?

Tags: c#, oledb

Is it possible to use windows username on data source of OleDB connection? I want to put excel file on Documents folder and extract info from it but I do not want to hard code username there. Is there anyway to get that username?

I am using Windows form.

```
con = new OleDBConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Test.xlsx; Extended properties=Excel 12.0;"
```

Comment: Hi John, some more information would help you get a fast answer. For example, things like how are you running this application? (web app, console app, etc.); what have you researched already to find the answer? You may have some luck googling terms like identity, current user, etc.

Comment: Look at `System.Environment.SpecialFolders`. You can get the `Documents` folder for the current user by following almost any example that uses that

Comment: I am using windows form.

Answer (score -1):

There are numerous ways to get the username. If you need the currently signed in user you can use `Environment.Username`. If you need a list of all the users in the current domain you can use the following method

```
public List<string> GetDomainUsers() 

var usersInCurrentDomain = new List<string>(); 

SelectQuery sQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount", $"Domain ='{Environment.UserDomainName}'");

ManagementObjectSearcher mSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(sQuery);

foreach (ManagementObject mObject in mSearcher.Get())
{
    product.Add(mObject["Name"]);
}
    return product;
}
```

If you're trying to access another users documents folder you'll either need to lessen the restrictions on that folder or act with administrative authority.

Alternately, unless this information is unique to each user, you may wish to put this information in a more neutral folder such as C:\ProgramData\MyApp or perhaps in one of the public folders. This would be a lot simpler.

Comment: If you need something more specific rephrase your question or leave a comment and I'll adjust this answer.